# Drupal Calendar - How to change week layout?

Tags: php, templates, drupal

I need to change the calendar week view, to be more user friendly.

Please check this screenshot, I am explaining the goal to reach on it:

https://www.diigo.com/item/image/4otf9/eb3r

https://www.diigo.com/item/image/4otf9/1qcb

The website has some dates for events, that are mainly during night. So, there are some events starting at 2AM for exemple. It doesn't make sense displaying these events in next day. For exemple, if the party starts on saturday night at 2AM, then it could me confusing for the user to display it on Sunday.. How can I adapt the week templates to start the day at 5AM (instead 00:00) and finish at 24:00 (instead 24:00)

And about multi-day dates, how to display them next to the single day dates??

Answer (score 0):

Change the `Settings` of the Calendar format in the Views and set the time grouping to `custom`. In the box, specify the intervals/start times that you want to show up starting at the hour you want to start at. See illustration below:

[image]

You can change the `Week` display like this too.